# Display posts to users which subscribed certain tags

Tags: mysql

Basically I would like to have `posts with tags` and `users with their tags subscription`
What shall be my structure? I would like to serve users the posts which contains tags that they subscribed.

Now I would like you to examine two cases

1) There are no tags - but categories  - one category per post

2) There are tags - many tags per post

In the second case should I have four tables and do an enormous join between them all ?

Comment: this is not a real mysql problem, your post tags vs user tags problem would require a nasty (pseudo-code) `SELECT poststoshow where EXISTS( SELECT posts where tags IN (SELECT tag from user...)`. This can also be speed up by the application above (eliminating the second select for instance since this will not change during page creation most likely)

Answer (score 2):

Table structure for your need

```
 Contentid  Topic Catgoryid  Tags
```

More than one tag can be separated by , and topic with no tag will be null . You can select topic for particular tag by using `like` in select query